# Multiple insert/update statements inside trigger?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

Just a quick question that no doubt someone out there will know the answer to.

I need to be able to do multiple insert/updates within a trigger. Every attempt ends with failure :(

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `Insert_Article`//
CREATE TRIGGER `Insert_Article` AFTER INSERT ON `Article`
 FOR EACH ROW insert into FullTextStore (`Table`, `PrimaryKey`, `ColumnName`, `Data`, `Created`) values ('Article', NEW.ArticleID, 'Description', NEW.Description, UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
//
```

At the moment, the above simply inserts a row into a table when the parent table inserts. This works fine.

To get this to work with mulitple values I need to do

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `Insert_Article`//
CREATE TRIGGER `Insert_Article` AFTER INSERT ON `Article`
 FOR EACH ROW insert into FullTextStore (`Table`, `PrimaryKey`, `ColumnName`, `Data`, `Created`)
select 'Article', NEW.ArticleID, 'Description', NEW.Description, UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
union
select 'Article', NEW.ArticleID, 'Keywords', NEW.Keywords, UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
//
```

But... There must be an easier way? When I try using ; to terminate each statement, it fails with

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL version for the right syntax to use near 'select 'Article', NEW.ArticleID, 'Keywords', 'NEW.Keywords, UNIX_TIMESTAMP())' at line 1
```

I can't even get multiple update statements to work.

It'd be a great help if anyone could point out what i'm doing wrong?

Cheers

Gavin

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From the docs:  [Create Trigger Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

> trigger_stmt is the statement to
>   execute when the trigger activates. If
>   you want to execute multiple
>   statements, use the BEGIN ... END 
>   compound statement construct. This
>   also enables you to use the same
>   statements that are allowable within
>   stored routines

```
CREATE TRIGGER testref BEFORE INSERT ON test1
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test2 SET a2 = NEW.a1;
    DELETE FROM test3 WHERE a3 = NEW.a1;
    UPDATE test4 SET b4 = b4 + 1 WHERE a4 = NEW.a1;
  END;
```

Comment: You are the person (being a PC world n all that).

Thank you very much. I think I had left out the BEGIN when using END.