# Mysql trigger with multiple actions

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I want to update two tables before insert into table `table1`, in phpmyadmin, but phpmyadmin displays error after creating this trigger (Error in MySQL syntax).

This works:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `my_trig`   
BEFORE INSERT ON `table1` 
FOR EACH ROW 
update table2 
set 
attr = attr+NEW.attr
where table2.id = NEW.id;
```

This works too (without the first trigger, of course):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `my_trig`   
BEFORE INSERT ON `table1` 
FOR EACH ROW 
update table3 
set 
attr = attr+NEW.attr
where table3.id = NEW.id;
```

But using `BEGIN- update1; update2; -END` it can´t be created. Any ideas how to create this type of trigger? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: old, but maybe still available : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921627/multiple-insert-update-statements-inside-trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have extra comma after the set statement

```
attr = attr + NEW.attr,
```

fix,

```
CREATE TRIGGER `my_trig`   
BEFORE INSERT ON `table1` 
FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE   table2 
SET     attr = attr + NEW.attr // <=== removed
WHERE   table2.id = NEW.id;
```

using `BEGIN-END`

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER `my_trig`   
BEFORE INSERT ON `table1` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    UPDATE   table2 
    SET     attr = attr + NEW.attr
    WHERE   table2.id = NEW.id;
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

- [MySQL Trigger Example](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/introduction-to-mysql-triggers/)