# Multiple Queries in Triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, triggers

I'm fairly new to using triggers and have a tiny question.
I have a trigger finds a match between a newly inserted enquiry and a customer table.

```
INSERT INTO customersmatched (customerID,enquiryID) SELECT id, NEW.id FROM customer AS c WHERE c.customerName=NEW.companyName HAVING COUNT(id)=1;
```

I then need to update the newly inserted enquiry so it has a status which shows it's matched (but only if it has matched). So I tried adding this line after the insert.

```
UPDATE enquiry SET status="Live-Enquiry" WHERE id IN ( SELECT enquiryID FROM customersmatched WHERE enquiryID = NEW.id);
```

Except I get this error:

> MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the >right
>   syntax to use near 'UPDATE enquiry SET status="Live-Enquiry" WHERE id
>   IN ( SELECT enquiryID FROM cus' at line 5

How do I allow multiple queries within a trigger. I've tried doing something like in this link: [Multiple insert/update statements inside trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921627/multiple-insert-update-statements-inside-trigger)

But doesn't work either. I'm using phpmyadmin btw. Can anyone help? :D

Answer (score 0):

If you have ansi quotes enabled then you can't use double quotes as a string literal, and need to use single quotes instead. see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes  Otherwise, I don't see any syntax errors that jump out at me.

Try changing `SET status="Live-Enquiry"` to `SET status='Live-Enquiry'`

**EDIT:**

What is the purpose of the first query? I'm not sure you need the `HAVING` in that query.  If want a distinct list of matches, just use `DISTINCT`

```
INSERT INTO customersmatched (customerID,enquiryID) 
SELECT DISTINCT id, NEW.id 
FROM customer AS c 
WHERE c.customerName=NEW.companyName;
```

The second query, if I understand it correctly, can be simplified to this:

```
UPDATE enquiry 
SET status='Live-Enquiry' 
WHERE id = NEW.id;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. It doesn't seem to be the quotes :/ The having is there as there are multiple matches occasionally and we only want matches where there is one match. The update is more convoluted as we need the insert to be successful for it to update. Cheers for your help though!

Comment: @abrosis I'm assuming you tried the accepted answer in the link you provided in the OP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921627/multiple-insert-update-statements-inside-trigger which says you need to use a `BEGIN` ... `END` block when using multiple statements in a trigger?