# MySQL Multiple triggers (using BEGIN/END) not able to be created

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger for an InnoDB database in MySql 5.6.20. I'd like to perform multiple queries for the same type of trigger and the BEGIN/END method (workaround?) seems to work for others here: [Multiple insert/update statements inside trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921627/multiple-insert-update-statements-inside-trigger)

```
CREATE Trigger tg_month_avg_tst AFTER UPDATE ON eventlog
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE month_avg set month = '9' where id = '585';
  END;
```

This fails with a SQL syntax error. If I remove `BEGIN` and `END;` the trigger gets added and functions correctly:

```
CREATE Trigger tg_month_avg_tst AFTER UPDATE ON eventlog
  FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE month_avg set month = '9' where id = '585';
```

What is preventing the trigger in the first example from being created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define another delimiter than `;`.

```
delimiter |
CREATE Trigger tg_month_avg_tst AFTER UPDATE ON eventlog
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE month_avg set month = '9' where id = '585';
  END
|
delimiter ;
```

Otherwise the DB will think your trigger definition ends at the first `;` which would make it incomplete, missing the `end` for the `begin`